# Changing fonts within math mode

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, fractions

I would like to get a mixed number like $3 \, 1/4$ written with `1` and `4` written is a slightly smaller script, and with the `1` moved up along the slash character and with the `4` moved down along the slash character.  The appearance should be similar to that seen in cookbooks.  ASCII codes 171 and 172 typeset `1/2` and `1/4` in this way, too.  (See `theasciicode.com.ar`.)

Comment: Package `nicefrac` and its `\nicefrac` command perhaps?, but I wouldn't use it for math typesetting

Comment: following up on the comment by @ChristianHupfer, `\nicefrac` is quite suitable for typesetting recipes, but not math.

Comment: You shouldn't try to typeset fractions in this way in maths. I like `nicefrac` because these fractions look much better in recipes, but recipes are not maths (even if their construction and use requires maths).

Comment: @cfr  There are other contexts in which I would like to typeset an expression in math mode with some digits typeset in `textstyle` font and other digits typeset in `scriptstyle`.   `TeX` already does this with expressions like `$1 \, \frac{3}{4}$`.  I just want to customize this.  Can I specify the font with a `makebox` command?

Comment: But that's a completely different kind of issue: you are not talking about moving things and using cookbook fractions in maths mode. You are just talking about using different styles/sizes within maths. But I don't understand what that has to do with the font or why you'd try to specify a font by making a box. Probably I just don't get it. @barbarabeeton might understand the kind of case you have in mind.

Comment: @cfr  In the mixed fraction `1 \, 3/4`, I would want `1` typeset in `textstyle` and the `3` and `4` typeset in a smaller font like `scriptstyle`, but I do not want `3/4` typeset using `\tfrac`.  I would like `3/4` to look more like it does using ASCII code 171 or 172.

Comment: Er ... that's the same context, isn't it? Not a different one. That is, it is just the same thing everybody keeps saying you shouldn't use in maths mode.

Comment: @cfr  I have other contexts in which I do want these mixed numbers typeset in math mode.  For example, in typesetting a test.

Comment: Why would a test require ugly typography and non-standard mathematical typesetting? But if you want that, you can do it using `nicefrac` as has already been said.

Comment: nobody has mentioned `\tfrac{x}{y}` which sets the numerator and denominator one above the other, in a smaller size.  it requires math mode.

Comment: @barbara beeton  Using `\tfrac{m}{n}` occupies too much vertical space.

Comment: @user74973 -- it's very difficult to answer your question sensibly, since it's not known what the context is.  the slashed fraction really doesn't belong in math environments.  if you had provided even a handwritten example of your intended use, it would have been possible to contribute more appropriate comments or answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\nicefrac` macro can be used in text or in math mode, but it **should not** be used in math mode because the output is not really nice, but you have been warned.

It is nice for cooking recipes or everyday's specification of some amount of fractions, but not for math!

I've defined a wrapper macro that allows for better markup internally:

Use

```
\dontuserecipefractionsinmathmodeandifyoudodontblamemeforthebadoutput
```

with care!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\dontuserecipefractionsinmathmodeandifyoudodontblamemeforthebadoutput}{omm}{%
  \IfValueT{#1}{\mathrm{#1}\,}%
  \nicefrac{#2}{#3}%
}

\begin{document}


\foreach \x in {1,...,10} {%

$\dontuserecipefractionsinmathmodeandifyoudodontblamemeforthebadoutput[\the\numexpr 2 *\x]{\x}{\the\numexpr 5*\x}$

}



The radiation zone of the Sun extends to about \nicefrac[\itshape]{5}{7} of the solar radius. 


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not include the context.  I need these fractions to be typeset in math mode.

Comment: The name of the command is rather ... lengthy, but it does typeset mixed numbers as I had requested.